# Submitting code snippets to database using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, database, xmlhttprequest, submit, code-snippets

In my website, I send data to a database using XMLHttpRequest. I tried submitting code snippets and simple Spanish language characters, but when I check the received data, I only see what comes after those code snippets or characters, like  this:

Data sent:
**Hello `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`**

Data received:
**Hello**

So, is there any way to submit code snippets or special characters using XMLHttpRequest? If there isn't, which is the best way besides php?

Here is my XMLHttpRequest code:

```
    //call the function for the XMLHttpRequest instance
    //create the variable that will contain the instance of the XMLHttpRequest object (initially with null value)
    var xmlHttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {//for Forefox, IE7+, Opera, Safari, ...
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else if(window.ActiveXObject) {//for Internet Explorer 5 or 6
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    //create pairs index=value with data that must be sent to server
    var data = "title="+title+"&desc="+desc;

    //sets the request
    xmlHttp.open("POST","http://mywebsite.com/database.php",true);          

    //adds a header to tell the PHP script to recognize the data as is sent via POST
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    //sends the request
    xmlHttp.send(data);

    //Check request status
    //If the response is received completely, will be transferred to the HTML tag with tagID
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("div").innerHTML=xmlHttp_refresh_es_ES.responseText;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always encode your data before sending it, that way spaces and special characters shouldn't be an issue (as long as it's UFT8)

```
var data = "title=" + encodeURIComponent(title) + "&desc=" + encodeURIComponent(desc);
```